# SQL Queries: Queries depending on previous queries and merging results

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, dependencies

Following problem:

Query 2 and Query 3 depend on the results of Query 1 and Query 4 depends on the results of query 2. How would you express these queries without executing the same query multiple times?

Example:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT id, color, part FROM T1
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT id, owner FROM T2 WHERE T2.color in (SELECT id, color, part FROM T1)
```

**Query 3**

```
SELECT id from T3 where T3.part in (SELECT id, color, part FROM T1)
```

**Query 4**

```
SELECT id from T4 where T4.owner in (SELECT id, owner FROM T2 WHERE T2.color in (SELECT id, color, part FROM T1))
```

**edit**

At the end i need the union of the result

```
Query1 union Query2 union Query3 union Query4
```

Now as you can see, I have copied and pasted the previous queries, there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: you can use JOIN syntax instead of IN

Comment: oh sorry, I left out that I have the union the result of each query

Comment: FYI your union result is impossible since you use **different fields in each result set**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need four different result sets?  How many rows are you expecting in each set and what kind of entities are T1, T2, T3, T4 - because it may be possible to combine those queries into a single set.

In addition, this:

```
SELECT id, owner FROM T2 WHERE T2.color in (SELECT id, color, part FROM T1)
```

isn't valid SQL, you probably mean:

```
SELECT id, owner FROM T2 WHERE T2.color in (SELECT color FROM T1)
```

Comment: sorry for the sql mistake ... i just wanted to come up with a simple example because the one i am working with is more complex, they all have the same entities but are subsets of the original table

Comment: @user944308 Are the subsets defined as views? It's difficult because it's not clear how T2 relates to T1. It might be a lot easier if you put the problem in plain English. MySQL doesn't yet support common table expressions/subquery factoring, so you probably will have to repeat the subqueries. However, that's not necessarily bad, since 1) the operation in each case might be individually optimized independently or 2) the optimizer may be able to combine them. I would worry about code quality and maintainability first, performance next (after seeing evidence of a problem in the execution plan).

Comment: @user944308, virtually every time someone simplies like this, they get the wrong answer because the complexity is part of the problem. Please don't do it inthe future.

Comment: Don't use subqueries when there is no need for. IN() can be slow when the subquery returns too many results. Use a JOIN, easier to read and understand as well.

Comment: @Frank Heikens While I agree that generally JOINs are be easier to read and clearer, JOIN is semantically different from IN.  IN is effectively going to remove duplicates from the set within the IN, while JOIN can cause cross-product-like effects.  As far as performance, often times they are identical because the optimizer can be very good at them (at least in SQL Server).  Like all queries, it helps to at least check the execution plan to ensure it isn't taking a very inefficient way to get the results you have declared.

Answer (score 1):

Just join them by the specific columns.

```
select * from T1  
inner join T2  on T1.color=T2.color 
inner join T3 on T3.part=T1.part 
inner join T4 on T4.owner=T2.owner
```